# SwiftUI intrinsicContentSize is wrong when trying to render a view to image

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimage

Right off the bat, I am trying to render a custom SwiftUI `View` into an UIImage, but I am having issues. This is one of my first forays into SwiftUI so I might be missing something fundamental.

The test app is a photo collage app and I have this base view.

[image]

Each purple frame is a button which allows the user to pick an image, and will add it in a ZStack as an Image.

Tapping save results in this 10x10 pts image.

[image]

The full code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  photoframer
//
//  Created by Jonathan on 12/11/22.
//

import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI
import PhotoLibraryPicker

struct Screenn<Content: View>: View {
    var viewToScreenShot: Content
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            viewToScreenShot
            Button("save") {
                let img = viewToScreenShot.snapshot()
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img!, nil, nil, nil)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Choose Photos")
    }
}

struct Frame2v1h: View {
    var padding: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: padding) {
                    HStack(spacing: padding) {
                        ImagePickerButton()
                        ImagePickerButton()
                    }
                    ImagePickerButton()
                }
            }
            .padding(padding)
            .border(.blue, width: 2)
    }
    
}

struct ImagePickerButton: View {
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State var pictures = [Picture]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !pictures.isEmpty {
                Rectangle()
                    .overlay (
                        pictures.first?.toImage(width: Int(pictures.first!.asset.pixelWidth), height: Int(pictures.first!.asset.pixelHeight), mode: .aspectFill)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                        )
                    .clipped()
            }
            Button {
                self.showImagePicker = true
            } label: {
                Text(pictures.isEmpty ? "+" : "+++")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .border(Color.purple, width: 5)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                PhotoLibraryPicker(self.$pictures)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func snapshot() -> UIImage? {
        
        // Note: since iOS 15 it seems these two modifiers are required.
        let controller = UIHostingController(
            rootView: self.ignoresSafeArea()
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
        )
        guard let view = controller.view else { return nil }
        
        let targetSize = view.intrinsicContentSize
        if targetSize.width <= 0 || targetSize.height <= 0 { return nil }
        
        view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

It seems like the issue is that the `let targetSize = view.intrinsicContentSize` is always 10x10.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong here? I've tried at least 10 snapshot solutions from SO and across the web.